# Secant method for e^(x) matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-analysis

I'm trying to code the secant method for f(x)=e^(-x)-sin(x) to find the smallest positive root. My code seems to be getting an error.

```
%// Initial values and tolerance
x(0) = 2;
x(1) = 10;
f = @(x) exp(-x)-sin(x);

error = 0.001;

%// Different iterations
for k=0:100

    x(k+1) = x(k) - (f(x(k)))*((x(k) - x(k-1))/(f(x(k)) - f(x(k-1))));

    if abs(x(k)-x(k-1)) < error
        return;
    end
end
```

Comment: at k=0, x(k-1) is x(-1) shouldnt the for loop start at 1.

Comment: well you cannot access `x(0)` in Matlab, so that should start at 2

Answer (score 1):

**Why an error?**

As noted in the comments to your question, [vector(1D matrix) indices in matlab run from `1` to `end`](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), so in your case, you try to access invalid indices at various locations in your code:

```
%// Initial values and tolerance
x(0) = 2;                         %// <-- invalid index
x(1) = 10;
f = @(x) exp(-x)-sin(x);

error = 0.001;

%// Different iterations
for k=0:100
                     %// for k=0: x(k) and x(k-1) both invalid indices
                     %// for k=1: x(k-1) invalid index
    x(k+1) = x(k) - (f(x(k)))*((x(k) - x(k-1))/(f(x(k)) - f(x(k-1))));

    if abs(x(k)-x(k-1)) < error
        return;
    end
end
```

**Corrected code**

We correct the invalid index cases above (changing also your `for` loop into a `while` loop):

```
%// Function to (attempt) to find a root to
f = @(x) exp(-x)-sin(x);

%// Initial values and tolerance
x(1) = 2;
x(2) = 10;
error = 0.001;

%// Different iterations
k=2;
maxIt = 100;
while (abs(x(k)-x(k-1)) > error) && (k-1 <= maxIt)
    x(k+1) = x(k) - f(x(k))*(x(k) - x(k-1))/(f(x(k)) - f(x(k-1)));
    k = k + 1;
end

%// print result
disp(['x(end) = ' num2str(x(end)) ...
  ', f(x(end)) = ' num2str(f(x(end))) ...
  ', iterations: ' num2str(k-2)]);
```

Yielding the result

```
x(end) = 6.285, f(x(end)) = -4.9315e-10, iterations: 7
```

Comment: I don't think changing from `for` to `while` makes it better. That's fancy for nothing even tho I understand why you use it.

Comment: @R.Bergamote Since I've included the iterator `k` in an invariant in the `while` loop expression/signature, I'd say it's a matter of taste, as the two loop variants, in this case, are very similar. It's valuable, however, that you point out that the `while` loop does in no way make it better (which I didn't explicitly state; however I realize such a statement could possibly be inferred by the reader, from the above). Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: From a code point of view it's exactly the same, however I wouldn't recommend it for debugging and understanding the code. Otherwise that's a really valid method

Comment: how can i find the smallest positive root?

Comment: I tried a tolerance with 0.0001 but I kept getting a high root? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user1979029 Since your function has several roots (and the method only finds on of them, at best), you'll have to adjust your initial values rather than the tolerance. Try e.g. `x(1) = 0`, `x(2) = 2`.

Comment: Oh I wanted the tolerance to be .0001. Sorry for the confusion! I get: x(end) = 34.5575, f(x(end)) = -3.9184e-15, iterations: 8. And this root is way too big. I know it should be around .58. I feel like I'm doing some type of error.

Comment: Have you tried the code above with the modifications to the initial values, `x(1) = 0` and `x(2) = 2` (and tolerance however you wish)? Using that myself, the script produces a root `x(end) = 0.58853`.